# Find the key-value pairs with key that has a length of 4

Tags: ruby, hash

Ruby file:

```
student_ages = {
"Jack" => 10,
"Jill" => 12,
"Bob" => 14
}
```

How can I select Jack and Jill pair from the Hash?

```
student_ages.select {|key| k.length <= 4}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
student_ages.select{|key, _| key.length == 4}
```

Comment: @Leventix Thanks for the fix. I am ashamed of that.

Comment: It seems to also work by omitting the 2nd parameter altogether: `student_ages.select{|key| key.length == 4}`

Comment: Prefer `|key,|` to `|key, _|`.

Comment: @dwenzel That is strange. I expect `key` in such case to be an array of a key-value pair, but that does not seem to be the case. You seem to be right.

Comment: @sawa Strange indeed..  `each` and `map` have the behavior you describe, with an array of key-value pair, but `select` and `reject` just take in the key.  I may pose a separate SO question about this.